# Best way to handle null exceptions when concatenating a string in C#?

Tags: c#, null

I have this line of code that can throw null exceptions.

```
singleAddress.FullAddress = cc.MailingAddressStreet1.ToString() + " " +
   cc.MailingAddressCity.ToString() + " " +
   cc.MailingAddressState.ToString() + " " +
   cc.MailingAddressZip.ToString() + " " +
   cc.MailingAddressCountry.ToString();
```

I know that I can fix it by adding if statements to check if it is null. But is there a better recommended way to do it?

I just want to learn how to handle such exceptions better (and not have to write more code than I need to). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well what do you *want* the result to be if any of these values is null? And what's the type of each value? (If it's already string, why are you calling ToString?)

Comment: Nothing. If someone did not provide a Country then the string should just not add anything.
I didn't think about that When I wrote the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: And my point about the needless calls to ToString?

Comment: no idea why I put the toString there. They were all string values. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Actually I realized that the .toString() was the reason why the exception was thrown out. I went back and removed all of them and the code worked fine. Now I know why you were asking about the toString :). Thanks @JonSkeet!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [String.Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx):

```
if (cc != null)
{
    singleAddress.FullAddress = string.Join(" ",
        cc.MailingAddressStreet1,
        cc.MailingAddressCity,
        cc.MailingAddressState,
        cc.MailingAddressZip,
        cc.MailingAddressCountry);
}
```

The [String.Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx) takes a variable number of `object` arguments and calls the [Object.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) on each argument that is not `null`.

Answer (score 3):

The `String.Join` method seems like a good way to go, but don't forget the null coalescing operator, e.g.

```
var s = (cc.MailingAddressStreet1 ?? string.Empty) + ...
```

I'm assuming that `cc.MailingAddressStreet1` is already a string though.

This gives you the option of using an alternative string when the string is null, e.g.

```
var s = (cc.MailingAddressStreet1 ?? "(n/a)") + ...
```

And don't forget the brackets :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably just use `string.Format`:

```
singleAddress.FullAddress = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}",
    cc.MailingAddressStreet1, cc.MailingAddressCity, cc.MailingAddressState,
    cc.MailingAddressZip, cc.MailingAddressCountry);
```

The `NullReferenceExceptions` were due to calling `ToString` - which will happen anyway for non-null values (even in your original code), and is pointless if the property types are already `string`...

Answer (score 1):

String.Concat should work

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx

```
singleAddress.FullAddress = String.Concat(cc.MailingAddressStreet1.ToString(), 
                                        " ", cc.MailingAddressCity.ToString(), 
                                        " ", cc.MailingAddressState.ToString(),
                                        " ", cc.MailingAddressZip.ToString(),
                                        " ", cc.MailingAddressCountry.ToString());
```

Comment: I still got the nullReferenceException with this one because MailingAddressCountry was null. But thanks for telling me about Concat.

Comment: Correction: It works if I remove the .toString. Sorry about that